# Filling not existing data with 0 SQL / Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

Please see below explanation of my problem. I have 2 tables.

```
[TABLE1: LocationsOFproducts - Keep data about location of products and quantity][1]

[TABLE2:  Datahistory - keep data about stock movement ( removing/adding product from/to stock )][2]

[QUERY1: SumDataHistoryQuery - Making Sum of Products moved from the same location][3]
```

[QUERY2: TOTAL QTY - Counting how many products left in some location after stock movement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8r83H.jpg)

SQL Code:

---

```
SELECT LocationsOFproducts.[Bay no]
    ,LocationsOFproducts.[Product Code]
    ,LocationsOFproducts.LocationQTY
    ,SumDatahistoryQuery.SumOfQTY
    ,([LocationQTY]) + ([SumOfQTY]) AS TOTALQTY
FROM LocationsOFproducts
INNER JOIN SumDatahistoryQuery ON (LocationsOFproducts.[Product Code] = SumDatahistoryQuery.[Product Code])
    AND (LocationsOFproducts.[Bay no] = SumDatahistoryQuery.[Bay no])
    AND (LocationsOFproducts.[Product Code] = SumDatahistoryQuery.[Product Code])
GROUP BY LocationsOFproducts.[Bay no]
    ,LocationsOFproducts.[Product Code]
    ,LocationsOFproducts.LocationQTY
    ,SumDatahistoryQuery.SumOfQTY
    ,([LocationQTY]) + ([SumOfQTY])
ORDER BY LocationsOFproducts.[Product Code];
```

---

RESULT:

I expect a little bit different result.
My query should check is there any more value with Bay no,product code and QTY in Datahistory table, if not  I want to fill that space with data from LocationOfproducts table and in the field SumOfQTY fill those
values with 0 to make a sum in TOTALQTY column.
Please see below what I need to get:

[Please see query what I need to get - I maked that in Photoshop by cutting and pasting fields:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ufjyz.jpg)

Can anyone know how to write the right query?

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.

Comment: Try to replace `INNER JOIN` with `LEFT JOIN`. That should leave _Null_ for those with a zero count. To have 0, use: `,Nz(SumDatahistoryQuery.SumOfQTY,0)`

Comment: Gustav resolved my problem. Thank you sow much !!!

Comment: @Gustav I noticed one more problem it working fine but if table Location of Product have duplicated values and I typing to remove some QTY from that location it removing QTY from both other just from one. I think it will be good to sum all Products from the Same location before removing/adding some QTY.Do you know what code I can add to query to resolve that problem? Please see picture from that link to see result of query [link] (https://s18.postimg.org/qbwuxevfd/duplicate.jpg)

Comment: Then you will need - in the query above - to replace the table with a query that groups the locations.

Comment: One more question. Right know my query making Sum of Products moved from the same location.But what if I want to move product to some location but in that location that product didn't exist? Did anyone know how to do that condition? : If someone type in the [Datahistory table] Product code,location and quantity but that product didn't exist in that location in the [table LocationsOFproducts] it will add that product code and location with quantity 0 to table [LocationsOFproducts] and making sum of qty from both tables in the [SumDataHistoryQuery].